# Automorphism of Graph $G^n$

Tags: graph-theory, finite-groups

I try to define the automorphism of $G^n$ where $G$ is a graph and $G^n = G \Box \ldots \Box G$,( $n$ times, $\Box$  is the graph product).
I think that : $\text{Aut}(G^n)$ is $\text{Aut}(G) \wr  S_n$ where $S_n$ is the symmetric group of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ but I have no idea how to prove it because I am a beginner in group theory. Can you help me or suggest me a reference on this subject ?  Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is a fantastic question.

Answer (score 2):

You are right, provided you assume that $G$ is prime relative to the Cartesian product, the automorphism group of the $n$-th Cartesian power of $G$ is the wreath product as you stated.

The standard reference for this is Hammack, Richard; Imrich, Wilfried; Klavžar, Sandi: Handbook of product graphs. (There is an older version of this, written by Imrich and Klavžar alone, which would serve just as well.) Unfortunately there does not seem to be much on the internet on this subject.

Comment: Thank you Chris, does this means that this property holds if $G=K_n$ where $K_n$ is the complete graph of $n$ vertices ?

Comment: Yes, definitely for $K_n$. (Note that the proofs are not bad, a few pages or so. The basic problem is to be able to recognize when a graph is a Cartesian product.)

Comment: What does it mean for $G$ to be prime relative to the Cartesian product?  I tried to prove this last nite and got stuck on a degenerate case that I assume this must eliminate.

Comment: Thanks again Chris.  I found a reference of Sabidussi saying that: $K_n$ is S-prime with regards to the direct product; I deduce it is    prime and thus, relatively prime ?

Comment: A graph is prime if it cannot be expressed as a Cartesian product of two non-trivial graphs. Since $K_n$ does not have an induced 4-cycle, it cannot be a non-trivial Cartesian product. Sabidussi and Vizing both proved that the "Cartesian factorization" of a connected graph is unique. (Connectedness is necessary.)

Comment: Thanks for this clarification.